# The multi-part identifier could not be bound sql for query spanning multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I inherited a stored procedure that I've been needing to modify for multiple projects and have come across this multi-part identifier error message:

`The multi-part identifier "schema.tablename" could not be bound`

schema being the schema I'm using in my DB, and of course tablename is the individual table name.

Here's the Sql query I have:

```
   CREATE TABLE #Results (TableNames nvarchar(50), ColumnContent nvarchar(250), Count int)
   SET NOCOUNT ON
   DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256)
   SET  @TableName = ''
   WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN
          SET @TableName =
          (
                 SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                 WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                       AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                       AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                                     OBJECT_ID(
                                            QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                                            ), 'IsMSShipped'
                                            ) = 0
          )
          WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL)
          BEGIN

               INSERT INTO #Results
               EXEC
               (
                      'SELECT ' + @TableName + ',[Column5], COUNT(*) FROM '+ @TableName +' ORDER BY NEWID()'
               )

          END   
   END
  SELECT * FROM #Results
  DROP TABLE #Results
```

basically I wanted to search through all the tables and for every table store the table name, the distinct content for the specified column, and the count for those distinct column values.  any help to see where my problem is would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My guess is that this is the culprit: `'SELECT ' + @TableName + ',[Column5], COUNT(*) FROM '+ @TableName +' ORDER BY NEWID()'`  The proc is attempting to display Schema.TableName as a column in the result set, right?  I'd try this:  `'SELECT ''' + @TableName + ''',[Column5], COUNT(*) FROM '+ @TableName +' ORDER BY NEWID()'`

Comment: I now get `msg 8120 -Column 'schema.tablename.columnname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`  apparently I have a bunch of problems.  how would I have the random portion (`NEWID()`) and the apparent need for `GROUP BY' ?

Comment: I was originally wanting a random sampling out of the table, so the query originally looked like this: `SELECT TOP 100 tablename, columnname, COUNT(*) FROM tablename ORDER BY NEWID()`

Comment: okay so I figured out the group by and order by issue.  I did this: `group by columnname order by 2 desc`.

Comment: @DMason if you set your suggestion as an answer i'll accept it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this is the culprit:

```
INSERT INTO #Results
    EXEC
    (
        'SELECT ' + @TableName + ',[Column5], COUNT(*) FROM '+ @TableName +' ORDER BY NEWID()'
    )
```

I'd try this:

```
INSERT INTO #Results
    EXEC
    (
        'SELECT ''' + @TableName + ''',[Column5], COUNT(*) FROM '+ @TableName +' GROUP BY [Column5] ORDER BY NEWID()'
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. also, I noticed that your second **while** loop will never end. I changed it to an IF

```
 CREATE TABLE #Results (TableNames nvarchar(50), ColumnContent nvarchar(250), Count int)
   SET NOCOUNT ON
   DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256)
   SET  @TableName = ''
   WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN
          SET @TableName =
          (
                 SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                 WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                       AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                       AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                                     OBJECT_ID(
                                            QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                                            ), 'IsMSShipped'
                                            ) = 0
          )
          print @Tablename
          IF (@TableName IS NOT NULL)
          BEGIN

               INSERT INTO #Results
               EXEC
               (
                       'SELECT ''' + @TableName + ''', [Column5],COUNT(*) FROM '+ @TableName 
               )

          END   
   END
  SELECT * FROM #Results`enter code here`
```

Comment: Thank you!!  I hadn't caught that!  too fixated on other things.

Comment: This doesn't fix my other issues, but it does fix the apparent infinite loop problem

Comment: Completely missed it. Copy paste syndrome... So I used a variable to print the dynamic statement and after fixing the error, in an effort to revert the code back to your version, I copied a bit of your original code and missed fixing the quotes again.